# Is window.state = 'fullscreen' from a background script supposed to work?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox-addon, fullscreen, firefox-addon-webextensions

<sup>Working with Xubuntu 14.04 and Firefox 45.0.1 here</sup>

I'm trying to automatically put a browser window into a fullscreen state from within a background script, if `location.hash == "#fullscreen"`.

This is requested from a privileged web page's script by doing a `postMessage()` that a content script listens for, which in turn delegates this request to the background script.

Everything works as expected, including the expected `console.log()` values in `background.js` (see the relevant source code snippets below) ... except, the window will not turn fullscreen; nothing actually happens, no console warning about requiring a user initiated event either, which I *would* receive had I tried something similar from the web page itself (which is why I turned to creating this extension, in the first place). Trying `w.state = 'minimized'`, for instance, doesn't do anything either.

Questions:

1. Is the Firefox WebExtensions API supposed to support `window.state` changes (already)?
2. If so, is the Firefox WebExtensions API supposed to be privileged enough to instigate fullscreen without explicit user interaction?
3. If so, should I be allowed to do this from the context I'm trying to do this?
4. Could (X)ubuntu or any Firefox preference be the culprit, perhaps?

---

Relevant `manifest.json` data:

```js
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
},

"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["*://privilegeduri/*"],
    "js": ["jquery-1.11.3.min.js", "content.js"],
    "run_at": "document_start"
  }
],

// I've tried without "fullscreen" as well
"permissions": [
  "tabs",
  "fullscreen", // no mention of this on MDN, but I tried it anyway
  "webNavigation"
]
```

The privileged web page script:

```js
if( location.hash == '#fullscreen' ) {
  if( hasExtension() ) { // function that evaluates whether my extension is installed
    window.postMessage( {
      action: 'requestFullscreen'
    }, 'http://privilegeduri' );
  }
}
```

The `content.js` script:

```js
function receiveMessage( e ) {
  if( e.source === window && e.origin === 'http://privilegeduri' ) {
    switch( e.data.action ) {
      case 'requestFullscreen':
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage( e.data );
      break;
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener( 'message', receiveMessage );
```

The `background.js` script:

```js
function receiveMessage( message, sender, sendResponse ) {
  if( sender.id === chrome.runtime.id && sender.url.match( /^http:\/\/privilegeduri/ ) ) {
    switch( message.action ) {
      case 'requestFullscreen':
        browser.windows.get( sender.tab.windowId, {}, function( w ) {
          console.log( w.state ); // outputs 'normal'
          w.state = 'fullscreen';
          console.log( w.state ); // outputs the expected value 'fullscreen'
        } );
      break;
    }
  }
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( receiveMessage );
```

Comment: Did you try the html5 fullscreen api - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API - ?

Comment: @Noitidart Yes, ultimately I've have gotten it to work with the fullscreen API. However, only within a restartless (bootstrapped) addon.The reason I started developing this extension to begin with, was because the fullscreen API is restricted to user initiation inside web pages. However, the WebExtensions API does not have elevated privileges in this regard either, unfortunately. :( And so, after failing with my OP example as well, my last hopes were set on the "legacy" restartless XPCOM API, which fortunately *does* have the elevated privileges for autonomous fullscreen activation. :-)

Comment: @Noitidart PS.: there's an `about:config` preference `full-screen-api.allow-trusted-requests-only` which might elevate the fullscreen API privileges as well, but that would mean I'd open the users of my addon up to *any* website having this privilege and I don't want to do that to my users, of course. :-) I only want my own website to have this privilege.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! From a jpm addon you can do the same, `getMostRecentWindow().fullScreen = true;`

Comment: @Noitidart Thanks for that suggestion! I just tried it out and you're right. However, that appears to be a slightly different kind of fullscreen mode (the <kbd>F11</kbd> kind). Since my website will also allow user initiated going in and out of fullscreen (with the html5 API), this conflicts with that functionality, since the <kbd>ESC</kbd> does not work with the <kbd>F11</kbd>-type of fullscreen. But good to know about that fullscreen possibility, in any case.

Comment: Oh very cool observation I didn't know about that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argh... I just came across the [`windows.update()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/windows/update) method and when I tried to set the `state` through the `updateInfo` parameter object it *did* give a notice:

> Type error for parameter updateInfo (Property "state" is unsupported by Firefox) for windows.update

That's a pitty.

Answer (score 1):

it's 2018 here and the codebase has changed. If you're working with Firefox Quantum then [windows.update()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/windows/update) now functions as intended. Here's a quick example:

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "WootFullscreen",
  "version": "9000.0.0.1",
  "description": "Sends woot, gets fullscreen.",
  "author": "Mekronid",
  "content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"], 
    "js": ["messagesender.js"]
  }
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["messagereciever.js"]
  },
"permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>"]
}
```

messagesender.js:

```
browser.runtime.sendMessage({message: "woot"})
```

messagereciever.js:

```
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(listener)

async function listener(findWoot) {
    console.log(findWoot.message)
    var val = await browser.windows.getCurrent()
    browser.windows.update(val.id, { state: "fullscreen"})
}
```